# Upgrading to springboot 2.5.12- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade to springboot 2.5.12. I am getting below error-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:254)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:267)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1365)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
at gov.nm.cses.gen.AppConfig.main(AppConfig.java:217)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 5 more

Any inputs appreciated.

Comment: ran into the same problem when upgrading the application to JDK17 and SpringBoot starter 2.6.7. Adding spring-context dependency, purging or deleting my .m2 did absolutely nothing...